# Terraform AWS Aurora Serverless MySQL - Error: Invalid DB Engine

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, terraform, serverless, amazon-aurora

I'm trying to use the aws terraform rds module to spin up an aurora serverless mysql 5.7 version but get the below Error while creating the DB Instance, pointing to an incorrect DBEngine.

***Error creating DB Instance: InvalidParameterValue: Invalid DB engine***

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "test" {
  cluster_identifier                  = "test-cluster"
  engine                              = "aurora-mysql"
  engine_version                      = "5.7.12"
  engine_mode                         = "serverless"
  database_name                       = "rdstest"
  master_username                     = "xxxxx"
  master_password                     = "xxxxxxx"
  kms_key_id                          = "arn:aws:kms:eu-west-1:792xxxxxx:key/09f01648-daf7-xxxxxxxx"
  backup_retention_period             =  7
  port                                = 3306
  db_cluster_parameter_group_name     = aws_rds_cluster_parameter_group.aurora_cluster_mysql_parameter_group.name
  vpc_security_group_ids              = ["${aws_security_group.cachet_rds.id}"]
  availability_zones                  = ["eu-west-1a"]
  db_subnet_group_name                = aws_db_subnet_group.cachet.id
  skip_final_snapshot                 = true
}

resource "aws_db_instance" "test" {
  identifier              = "test"
  allocated_storage       =  20
  storage_type            = "gp2"
  engine                  = "aurora-mysql"
  engine_version          = "5.7.12"
  instance_class          = "t3a.small"
  db_subnet_group_name    = aws_db_subnet_group.cachet.id
  vpc_security_group_ids  = ["${aws_security_group.cachet_rds.id}"]
  username                = "xxxxx"
  password                = "xxxxx"
  parameter_group_name    = aws_rds_cluster_parameter_group.aurora_cluster_mysql_parameter_group.name
  skip_final_snapshot     = true
  backup_retention_period = 5
  storage_encrypted       = true
  kms_key_id              = "arn:aws:kms:eu-west-1:79xxxxx:key/09f01648-daf7-47e7-af2f-xxxxxx"
}

resource "aws_db_parameter_group" "aurora_db_mysql_parameter_group" {
  name        = "test-aurora-parameter-group"
  family      = "aurora-mysql5.7"
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster_parameter_group" "aurora_cluster_mysql_parameter_group" {
  name        = "test-aurora-cluster-parameter-group"
  family      = "aurora-mysql5.7"
}
```

According to AWS Docs, the allowed family group is "aurora-mysql5.7" and engine_version is "5.7.12" .https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Updates.serverless_2_07_01.html

Tried with  EngineVersion: "5.7.mysql_aurora.2.08.2", and EngineVersion 5.7.12 both.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because of a **spelling mistake**:

```
engine                  = "aurora-msql"
```

The available engines are listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html#cfn-rds-dbinstance-engine). Thus there should be:

```
engine                  = "aurora-mysql"
```

Please note that there could be other errors, which are not apparent yet. But your issue of `InvalidParameterValue: Invalid DB engine` is most likely due the the spelling mistake.